# Using an implemented ontology(Protege) in Netbeans through Java

Tags: java, netbeans, jena, ontology, protege

Step 1 :
I have created an ontology using Protege.  I store it as an RDF/XML file.

Step 2:
I have created a user interface using Netbeans & Java.

i want now to import my ontology in my Netbeans project and interact with it.

How can i do that? 
It was suggested to me that i should use Jena.
I have already installed latest Jena version in my Netbeans project. However im not sure if i have done this correctly.

After adding the jena libraries i tried to do that:

Ont m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null);

and i get this when i try to run my program:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I have a good knowledge of java but i have to say that im very new to ontologies and i have never done this before.

Please help me to understand what im doing wrong or what i should do to make things right.
Thank you!

Comment: You might want to fix that, but it's just a WARNing, so you don't actually _have_ to do anything about it.  Is something not working?

Answer (score 0):

That warning you get, it might be you are missing a log4j library in you NetBeans project. You can download it in the link http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html and try to add the log4j*.jar file to your project Libraries.